# What happens in memory if we just declare a variable without initialization in java?

Tags: java

What happens in memory if we just create a reference variable or declare a variable for primitive data types or reference data types without initializing with any value as below?

```
int x;

Employee emp;
```

So what exactly happens in memory in both the cases?

Is any memory allocated at this stage or does it point to any random location or points to null or points to garbage values?

As in the 2nd case, only space will created in memory if we create a object using the constructor with new operator or using any other ways like.

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13788067/why-is-it-possible-to-declare-a-variable-without-an-initial-value

Comment: If those are instance variables they will be initialized to `0` (zero) and `null` if those are local variables the code will not compile. This is documented in the language specification.

Comment: @ChristofferPasser the question is something else! What actually happens.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sounds like a reasonable answer.

Comment: Why the downvotes on this question? The author asks a legitimate question.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name @MouseEvent i agree with your thoughts, but i'm concern about the reference variable intialization...when it initialized with `null` so what happens in memory layout? if it initialize with `null` value automatically then it must be that `emp` variable is created in memory which is pointing to `null` value means its presence in memory is must to have `null` value also . so exactly how its working internally in the context of memory allocation ?

Answer (score 5):

The Java Virtual Machine (JVM) allocates heap memory from the operating system and manages its own heap for Java applications afterwards. When an application creates a new object (e.g. `Employee emp = new Employee()`), the JVM assigns a continuous area of heap memory to store it.

While an object is not initialized (e.g. `Employee emp = null`), there is no need to allocate any memory. Primitive types (in the global scope), however, are initialized with a default value, even if you do not set it explicitly (e.g. `int x` is in fact `int x = 0`). So in this case, memory will be allocated, too.

As long as a reference to the object is kept anywhere within the application, the object remains in memory. Objects that are no longer referenced will be disposed by the garbage collector (GC) and will be cleared out of the heap to reclaim their space.

The `String` class also allocates heap memory, uses a little tweak though: [String interning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) is used, as soon as you allocate multiple instances of `String` with the same text. So, in fact you will only have one instance in memory, but multiple variables that reference it.

Answer (score 4):

If they are instance variables and you don't assign any values

Then for **primitives** the following default values are assigned:

**boolean**:        *false*

**byte** :          *0*

**char** :          *\u0000*

**short** :         *0*

**int**  :          *0*

**long**  :         *0L*

**float**  :        *0.0f*

**double**  :       0.0d

**Objects** are initialized to *null*

**Local** variables or variables inside methods have to be initialized before they are used or else your code won't compile.

Comment: Note about the last comment: they must be initialized **before they are used**. `int a; a=5;` is legal, `int a; int b = a;` does not compile

Answer (score 0):

Primitive types will be initiated with the default values (0 for int, false for boolean, ...). So it will use the memory size of the type (32 bits for int). [See the doc for default values and size](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Other objects will be initialized to `null` thus using only the reference (usually native pointer size 32 or 64 bits, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/981130/369946)) in memory.