# case switch java compile error

Tags: java, switch-statement, case

I wrote the following code but get the following compile error:

> The local variable dirArrow may not have been initialized. Note that
>   a problem regarding missing 'default:' on 'switch' has been
>   suppressed, which is perhaps 
>        related to this problem

```
//return the ID of the robot and arrow of his facing direction
public String toString(){
    char dirArrow;
    switch (direction) {
        case UP: dirArrow= '^';
        case RIGHT: dirArrow= '>';
        case DOWN: dirArrow= 'V';
        case LEFT: dirArrow= '<';
        break;

    }
    return (Integer.toString(RoboID) + dirArrow);
}
```

Comment: add a `default` case after your last case, as the error message says. Also you should use `break` after every `case` or else it will fall-through.

Comment: default in switch is not strictly necessary, in your case I would probably just omit myself.

Comment: 4 answers which *all* recommend initializing a `char` variable with a `null` value? Yikes!

Comment: And now most of the answers have changed to try using `''` which isn't a valid character literal either. Yikes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize your `dirArrow` variable like:

```
char dirArrow = ' ';
switch (direction) {
```

Read why local [variable should be initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560685/why-must-local-variables-including-primitives-always-be-initialized-in-java).

**Note:** also you need to add a `break` statement to the end of each case block like:

```
case UP: {
    dirArrow= '^';
    break;
}
```

Comment: Also mention that `break;` should be added after *each* `case`.

Comment: `null` isn't a valid `char`.

Comment: This still isn't the cleanest approach, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems there

1. You haven't initialize the method local variable `dirArrow`, initialize it like `char dirArrow = ' ';`
2. You don't have break at the end of each case. If you don't add break at the end of each case, for the first case, it will run all the case statements below that.

---

```
switch (direction) {
        case UP: dirArrow= '^'; break;
        case RIGHT: dirArrow= '>'; break;
        case DOWN: dirArrow= 'V'; break;
        case LEFT: dirArrow= '<'; break;

}
```

Comment: How do you expect `char dirArrow = null;` to compile?

Comment: char dirArrow = ''; doesnt work also, only with space between the ' '

Comment: @YuvalLevy : Yes, there should be a space, like `' '`

Answer (score 0):

its very much clear from the error that you have to initialize the local variable like   ''
like

```
char dirArrow='';
```

Comment: if I am trying char dirArrow=null; i get: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from null to char" error

Comment: `null` is not a valid value for `char`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for poiting out the mistake

Comment: `''` isn't a valid character literal either... and this isn't the cleanest fix anyway.

Answer (score 0):

either initialise the variable at declaration: `char dirArrow = 0;` or add a default block:

```
switch (direction) {
    case UP: dirArrow= '^';
    case RIGHT: dirArrow= '>';
    case DOWN: dirArrow= 'V';
    case LEFT: dirArrow= '<';
    break;
    defalut: dirArrow = 0;
}
```

BTW: for your code to work as expected, you should add a break after each case statement:

```
switch (direction) {
    case UP: dirArrow= '^';    break;
    case RIGHT: dirArrow= '>'; break;
    case DOWN: dirArrow= 'V';  break;
    case LEFT: dirArrow= '<';  break;

    defalut: dirArrow = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what you want to happen if the direction isn't any of those values. Maybe that's *currently* the full set of directions, but in the future it may not be - and fundamentally the Java compiler doesn't check that you've covered every enum possibility. (You're also missing `break` statements, as noted by other answerers.)

Personally I'd change the approach and get rid of the `switch` entirely: add a `toChar` method to `Direction`, and then you can just use:

```
return Integer.toString(RoboID) + direction.toChar();
```

Your enum constructor would take the character to use as well, so it would be very easy to implement.

*Much* cleaner, IMO. The only downside is that it ties your character representation to the `Direction` enum which may be intended to be UI-neutral. If that's the case, I'd have a `Map<Direction, Character>` instead, and you can use it very simply:

```
return Integer.toString(RoboID) + DIRECTION_CHARS.get(direction);
```

If you want to stick with the `switch` statement, I *wouldn't* add an initial value to the variable as others have suggested - I'd throw an exception in the `default` case:

```
@Override public String toString() {
    char dirArrow;
    switch (direction) {
        case UP:
            dirArrow= '^';
            break;
        case RIGHT:
            dirArrow= '>';
            break;
        case DOWN:
            dirArrow= 'V';
            break;
        case LEFT:
            dirArrow= '<';
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected direction! " + direction);
    }
    return (Integer.toString(RoboID) + dirArrow);
}
```

That's assuming it really isn't valid to have a `direction` other than the ones you've listed. Now, if you add a direction and forget to update this method, you'll end up with an exception rather than silent bad data.

The reason to not use a "dummy" initial value for the variable is that it doesn't express your desired behaviour. If you were to describe the method to someone in words, you would never mention that value, unless you *really* have a default value (e.g. space), in which case it's absolutely the right way to go.

Comment: I think it should be like `doNothing` for `default`. Because other than specified keys none is an action key.

Comment: @Ravinder: It's not clear what you mean, but it looks to me like the OP *expects* `direction` to be one of those enum values.

Comment: Yes I understand that. But not sure, unless it is an action key, how OP is going to use the return value.

Comment: @Ravinder: So why would you assume that the right return value would be `doNothing`? If the system isn't in an expected state, I'd normally prefer an exception so I can find out about that quickly...

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is to change the enum

```
enum Direction {
    UP("^"), DOWN("v"), LEFT("<"), RIGHT(">");
    public final String arrow;
    private Direction(String arrow) {
       this.arrow = arrow;
    }
}

// in your Robot class.
public String toString(){
    return RoboID + direction.arrow;
}
```

BTW I would use `roboID` for a field name.

Comment: Would you really make it a public field rather than introducing a method?