# Variable not initialized when checking for input error

Tags: java, initialization

New to the site and plan to use it a lot since I am in school for computer science. Im trying to do an error check in java on making sure a hex is enter however im being told that the string input isnt intialized.

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);



String input;


Pattern legalInput = Pattern.compile("a-fA-F0-9");
Matcher match = legalInput.matcher(input);
boolean answer = match.find();
int counterA = 0;
while (counterA < 1) {
    System.out.print("Please enter a hex number:");
    input = keyboard.nextLine();
    int counter = 0;
    while (counter < 1) {

        if (answer == true )
            counter++;
        else System.out.println("Error");
        } counterA++;
    }
```

Since this is my first programming language im learning in so lost any and all help is apperciated!

Comment: You have to initialize method local variables before using them. In your case, use `input=null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't assign `Matcher` with input you don't have yet.

```
String input;
Pattern legalInput = Pattern.compile("a-fA-F0-9");
// Matcher match = legalInput.matcher(input); // <-- input isn't set yet.
```

Move it into your `while` loop, just after you assign `input` -

```
input = keyboard.nextLine();
Matcher match = legalInput.matcher(input); // <-- now input is set.
```

Answer (score 0):

Make string `input` equal something to initialise it.

```
String input = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Always initialize your variables, go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560685/why-must-local-variables-including-primitives-always-be-initialized-in-java)

in your case initialize input as null or your default value.

for example:

```
 String input=null;
```

Addition to this try to close the resource as it will create a `Resource leak`

```
 keyboard.close();
```