# Error "variable zahl might not have been initialized

Tags: java, variables

I am writing a program and there is only one error left.

It says `variable zahl might not have been initialized`, but I did it:

```
public class Primzahltest1 { 
    public static void main (String[]argv) {
        int zahl;
        IO.readInt("...");
        if (zahl<=1) {
            IO.println ("...");
            return;
        }
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Just write `int zahl = 0;`. Or any other value you want.

Comment: You need to assign a value to `zahl`.

Comment: `int zahl = IO.readInt("...");`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize you `int` variable with the result of `readInt`

```
int zahl = IO.readInt("...");
```

otherwise, this means it is unitialized

```
int zahl;
```

and this means that what your input gets discarded

```
IO.readInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you declare a variable inside a method you should initialize it like

`int zahl=0;`

Comment: Not necessarily, value can be inserted with entered values.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what is wrong in my comment and example?

Comment: @Rehman, you answer is perfectly correct, local variables should be initialised,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560685/why-must-local-variables-including-primitives-always-be-initialized-in-java otherwise if `IO.readInt("...")` will throw an error, for example somebody pass string or not integer char it will remain not initialised.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize the variable `zahl` you only defined it. Instead of 
`int zahl;`
type
`int zahl=0` and the variable will be initialized
Or if you wish to make `zahl` inputted from the user write: `int zahl = IO.readInt("...");`

Answer (score 0):

You did not initialize the variable `zahl`, so you cannot test its value. That, in combination with the fact that you're reading an int but ignoring it makes me assume you intended to assign the int you read to `zahl`:

```
int zahl = IO.readInt("...");
```

Answer (score 0):

In your program you have not initialised zahl. You have only declared it.

For you to initialise it just equate zahl to the readInt.

```
int zahl = IO.readInt("...");
```

This would solve your problem.

In Java it is necessary to initialise all local variables so that you wont accidentally read something you didn't intend to.