# local variable initialization and switch selection

Tags: java

I'm novice in learning java, in this example that try to simulate roll dice game.

Compiler error appears when I do not initialize `myPoint` variable, so I set it to zero before `switch` construct.

I want to understand why do I need to initialize `myPoint` variable when it's value is set to value of `sumOfDice` within switch after it is declared,  **Unlike**  `gameStatus` variable?

```
  /***** roll dice game ****/

 //some code here..

   private enum Status { CONTINUE, WON, LOST };

   // plays one game of craps
   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
      // point if no win or loss on first roll
      int myPoint = 0; 
      Status gameStatus; // can contain CONTINUE, WON or LOST

      int sumOfDice = rollDice(); // first roll of the dice

      // determine game status and point based on first roll 
      switch ( sumOfDice ) 
      {
         case SEVEN: // win with 7 on first roll
         case YO_LEVEN: // win with 11 on first roll           
            gameStatus = Status.WON;
            break;
         case SNAKE_EYES: // lose with 2 on first roll
         case TREY: // lose with 3 on first roll
         case BOX_CARS: // lose with 12 on first roll
            gameStatus = Status.LOST;
            break;
         default: // did not win or lose, so remember point         
            gameStatus = Status.CONTINUE; // game is not over
            myPoint = sumOfDice; // remember the point
            System.out.printf( "Point is %d\n", myPoint );
            break; // optional at end of switch
      } // end switch 

// rest of the code here ..

      // display won or lost message

   // roll dice, calculate sum and display results
   public static int rollDice()
   {
       // return sum of dice
    } 
} // end class Craps
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560685/why-must-local-variables-including-primitives-always-be-initialized-in-java

Comment: The code you provided would not fail if myPoint is not initialized. You probably use the myPoint variable somewhere outside the `default` block, where it might be uninitialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Java specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html)

> A local variable (§14.4, §14.14) must be explicitly given a value before it is used, by either initialization (§14.4) or assignment (§15.26), in a way that can be verified using the rules for definite assignment (§16).

The [rules](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-16.html#jls-16.2.9) for switch statement effectively enforce you to initialize your variable in every possible execution path for the switch statement.

**So the answer is:**

- `gameStatus` variable is initialized in every possible execution path through the switch statement, therefore compiler is satisfied.
- `myPoint` would not be initialized if, e.g., `sumOfDice` were `SEVEN`, therefore the compiler forces you to initialize the variable outside the switch block

Answer (score 0):

In your `switch-case`, any path will initialize the `gameStatus` variable.

This is not the case for `myPoint` , so the compiler complains about the missing initialization .