# stop Java switch case from requiring an input

Tags: java, switch-statement

Hi my code compiles fine but when i run it i have to first enter the "mark" and then i need to enter the case. How do i alter the code so i do not need to enter anything for the case?

I know I can use a `while` loop or just else if but i want to get this working with `switch` case.

```
  import java.util.*;                                                             
  public class GradeCalcCASE {                                                                               
       public static void main(String[] args) {                                                                                   
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);                                        
       int choice;                                                                 
       double m;                                                                   
       //Sets ^^^ m as the mark that the user inputs                               
       System.out.println("Please enter the mark");                                
       m = sc.nextDouble();                                                        
       choice = sc.nextInt();                                                      
       if(m<0) {choice = 1;}                                                   

       else if(m>100) {choice = 2;}                                            

       else if(0<=m && m<50) {choice = 3;}                                     
    switch(choice) {                                                   
      case 1:                                                                     
      System.out.println("Invalid mark");                                         
      break;                                                                      

      case 2:                                                                     
      System.out.println("Invalid mark");                                         
      break;                                                                      

      case 3:                                                                     
      System.out.println("F");                                                    
      break;                                                                      

      }                                                                           
    }                                                                           
  }
```

Comment: "stop switch case from requiring input" ? ehm .. what do you mean by that? you want to do something like: switch() { case "one": ... } ??

Comment: currently when i run the program it asks firstly for the mark to be input then it sits and waits for another int to be entered. Sorry if i cant explain it better im new to the java world.

Comment: May be you mean the 'default' case which gets executed once neither of the cases are true?

Comment: @Ash change line 12 to `choice = 0;`

Comment: @Ash that has nothing to do with your switch, that is your: m = sc.nextDouble();                                                        
 12     choice = sc.nextInt();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `choice = sc.nextInt();` (at line 12) from your code and initialize `choice` with value '0' as `int choice = 0;` (at line 7)

Comment: Thanks @Prasann that worked a treat. Out of curiosity what does setting the choice value to '0' do?

Comment: @Ash `choice = sc.nextInt();` waits for input from the input stream hence you program hanged after entering the mark. Setting it to zero just initialises the variable to zero so that it can be set later from your switch statement

Comment: @Ash, You would need to initialize the variables before you can use them. In your case as you had set `choice = sc.nextInt();` earlier, it wasn't asking to initialize the variable. One you remove this statement without initializing it, the compiler would report error. Look at this SO post for more details - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560685/why-must-local-variables-including-primitives-always-be-initialized-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Here is the line where your program waits for `choice` input:

`choice = sc.nextInt();`

You just need to remove/comment it.

Also note that `choice` calculation conditions do not cover range `m >= 50 && m <= 100`.

Comment: Food for thought @Ash: you didn't need or want additional input, so why did you think `choice = sc.nextInt();`, was necessary or even appropriate?