# If we print a variable without initialize java show compile time error, but print a same variable inside a method it doesn't show error

Tags: java

```
public class memory {
    int b;

    public void main() {
        int a;
        System.out.println(a); /* complie time error */
        System.out.println(b); /* here works how */
    }
}
```

**which assigns a default value to b**

Comment: b is a class level variable. Both types (static/instance) of those get default values. Local variables don't. It's how Java is designed

Comment: Local variables and fields are just treated differently.

Comment: You have this exactly back to front. It is the uninitialised variable declared inside the method that causes the compiler error message.

Comment: @user207421 no, it's trying to use the uninitialised variable that causes the error.

Comment: [jls-4.12.5. Initial Values of Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5) - *A local variable (§14.4, §14.14) must be explicitly given a value before it is used, by either initialization (§14.4) or assignment (§15.26), in a way that can be verified using the rules for definite assignment (§16).*

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html under section Default Values

Comment: No, it is using the uninitialised variable *declared in the method* that is causing the error, which is contrary to the apparent meaning of your title. There are two uninitialised variables here, and only one gives the error.

Comment: @user207421 indeed, that's what I'm saying. It isn't the uninitialised variable declared in the method that causes it, it's using said variable. Also: it's not my question, so also not my title :)

Comment: Thanks, Guys. I am asking the default constructor to provide default values(when we creating objects). Here object doesn't play a role. So how instance variable have values.

Comment: @Stultuske So that's what I said in the first place. To the OP.

Comment: @user207421 you said: "It is the uninitialised variable declared inside the method that causes the compiler error message." which is not the case. It's using the variable.

Comment: @GOPALAKRISHNAN You can't initialize a method-local variable in a constructor. Once again you have it back to front. It is the method-local variable that needs initialising, not the instance variable.

Comment: @Stultuske Context please. 1. I was addressing the OP. 2. I was telling him that he was looking at the wrong variable. 3. Which he still is.

Comment: Similar Discussion - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560685/why-must-local-variables-including-primitives-always-be-initialized-in-java

Answer (score 1):

You are using an uninitialized variable within a method and Java requires those to be initialized before you use them. They don’t get a default value. Class member variables and static variables do get a default value but not variables used within your method code.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is class members are implicitly initialized, local variables are not.

Each type has a default, and obvious, value. For `int` it’s `0`.

So these two class fields will have the same value are the instance in constructed:

```
public class memory {
    int field1;
    int field2 = 0;
```

You can’t access a (potentially) uninitialised variable.  So to use a variable/field, no code path must exist that doesn’t result in a value being assigned to the variable.

For class fields, they are assigned the default value is one isn’t specified in the declaration. Local variables do not.