# Unassigned local variable in one time of several?

Tags: c#, .net, struct, unassigned-variable

I have next code:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     byte currency;
     decimal amount;
     if (Byte.TryParse("string1", out currency) && Decimal.TryParse("string2", out amount))
     {
        Check(currency, amount);
     }
     Check(currency, amount); // error's here
  }

  static void Check(byte b, decimal d) { }
```

and get next error:

> Use of unassigned local variable
>   'amount'

Why am I getting it at all and this is legal, why only for `amount`? Why `currency` in this case is assigned and `amount` - not?

Comment: See this question for additional information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542824/c-initialization-of-instance-fields-vs-local-variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this line (which I've separated onto two lines):

```
if (Byte.TryParse("string1", out currency) &&
    Decimal.TryParse("string2", out amount))
```

The `&&` operator is a **short-circuit** evaluation, which means that if the first `Byte.TryParse` does not succeed, then the second `Decimal.TryParse` will never get executed at all.

`currency` will always be assigned because `TryParse` sets the `out currency` ref to the default value if it fails to parse.  However, `amount` will still be undefined in this case.  It's as if you wrote the code like this:

```
if (Byte.TryParse("string1", out currency))
{
    if (Decimal.TryParse("string2", out amount))
    {
        Check(currency, amount);
    }
}
Check(currency, amount);
```

This should make it more obvious what's going on.  The part inside the first `if` statement always gets executed and assigns a value to `currency`.  The part inside the *second*, nested `if` statement will only get executed if the first one succeeded.  Otherwise, `amount` will have no value by the time you hit the second `Check`.

If you want to use the default values if the `currency` can't be parsed, then just initialize the locals to the default values:

```
byte currency = 0;
decimal amount = 0;
if (Byte.TryParse("string1", out currency) &&
    Decimal.TryParse("string2", out amount))
{
// Etc.
```

Or you can simply parse both of them, as @Martin said.

Answer (score 1):

It is just a compiler warning meant to keep you from using unassigned variables (though I think you understand that).  I can't explain why you are only getting it when using one of the unassigned variables and not the other.

Answer (score 1):

Chapter 5.3 of the C# Language Specification discusses this.  It is a beefy chapter, but it sure looks to me that the compiler should also have emitted an error for the unassigned "currency" variable.  It gets interesting if you comment out the if() statement and block, now the compiler suddenly wises up.  Even though "currency" was never used in the commented code.

That can't be right, I think you found a bug.  If Eric Lippert doesn't pass by, you can report the bug at connect.microsoft.com

Comment: It's not a bug.  The first `TryParse` will always get executed and set the out arg to the default value; the second `TryParse` will not get executed if the first one fails, so the value of `amount` may be undefined, but the value of `currency` will not be.

Comment: Oops, you're right.  I didn't see the TryParse calls using different out arguments.

Comment: If there's something you want to bring to my attention you can always use the contact link on my blog.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because there is a path in your program for which the compiler cannot guarantee that `amount` is assigned an initial value: when the first `TryParse()` fails. That's why you get the error on the line where you try to use `amount`.

[From MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx%28VS.71%29.aspx)

A variable passed as an out argument need not be initialized. However, the out parameter must be assigned a value before the method returns.

You can work around it by assigning default values to your local variables:

```
 decimal amount = 0;
```

Else you have to ensure that both `TryParse()` calls are made in any case, e.g (not really nice code):

```
bool b1 = Byte.TryParse("string1", out currency);
bool b2 = Decimal.TryParse("string2", out amount);

if (b1 && b2) {...}
```

BTW: this code fragment will also produce the same compiler error, because `a` is not assigned a value:

```
int a, b=1;
int c = a+b;
```

Comment: @Martin: Struts gets it's value by default, isn't it?

Comment: @Martin: I don't think it will fail at all when run, only in the IDE as a warning.  Both TryParse calls should fail, so why is the warning only showing up for the decimal one, and not the byte one?

Comment: @abatischev ah, yes.  An error in C# by default, a warning in VB.  Only an error in the IDE though, right?  I think the code would actually work, if you disabled that error.