# Variable scope in C#

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I am reading Beginning C# to refresh my memory on C# (background in C++).

I came across this snippet in the book:

```
int i;
string text;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   text = "Line " + Convert.ToString(i);
   Console.WriteLine("{0}", text);
}
Console.WriteLine("Last text output in loop: {0}", text);
```

The snippet above will not compile - because according to the book, the variable text is not initialized, (only initialized in the loop - and the value last assigned to it is lost when the loop block is exited.

I can't understand why the value assigned to an L value is lost just because the scope in which the R value was created has been exited - even though the L value is still in scope.

Can anyone explain why the variable text loses the value assigned in the loop?.

Comment: He asked for someone to explain why...

Comment: Sry, my fault. +1 then, even if I dont get which value should get lost since everything would stay in scope. 
edit: again, what are L and R values? :D

Comment: @fielding: lvalue usually means a value that can be assigned to, an rvalue is any expression, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_%28computer_science%29

Comment: @0xA3 Ty, haven´t heard of that yet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The variable does not "lose" its value. You get the compiler error because there is a code path where `text` is not assigned to (the compiler cannot determine whether the loop body is entered or not. This is a restriction to avoid [overly-complex rules in the compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y7h161d.aspx)).

You can fix this by simply setting `text` to `null`:

```
string text = null;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   text = "Line " + Convert.ToString(i);
   Console.WriteLine("{0}", text);
}
Console.WriteLine("Last text output in loop: {0}", text);
```

Note that I also moved the declaration of the loop index variable `i` into the `for` statement. This is best-practice because variable should be declared in the smallest possible declaration scope.

Comment: Good explanation (+1), but funny how 3 out of 5 answers write "loose" instead of the correct "lose" :-)

Comment: @Gorpik: Thanks for the correction. For me as non-native speaker it's always hard to get this right ;)

Comment: +1: the answer is encapsulated in this statement: "there is a code path where text is not assigned to ..."

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to initialize as text=string.empty ? than using null

Answer (score 4):

This does not compile not because `text` looses it's value after you exit `for`, but because compiler does not know if you will enter `for` or not, and if you not then `text` will not be initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but the value doesn't get lost on my machine...

Somewhat relevant may be this question here about what the compiler allows to be uninitialized vs. what not:

[Initialization of instance fields vs. local variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542824/c-initialization-of-instance-fields-vs-local-variables)

Answer (score 0):

```
     // Your code has compile time error - Use of unassigned local variable 'text'  
     //'text' variable hold last value from loop On Execution time not on Compile time.
```