# Variable default value in Java

Tags: java, variables

Every type in Java has a primitive value when declared. The article *[Primitive Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)* contains a description for primitive data types. Knowing this, why does Eclipse show an error telling me the variable may not have been initialized?

If I have, for example,

```
int x;
x++;
```

Comment: only local variables are not initialized by default

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the reference:

> Local variables are slightly different; the compiler never assigns a default value to an uninitialized local variable. If you cannot initialize your local variable where it is declared, make sure to assign it a value before you attempt to use it. Accessing an uninitialized local variable will result in a compile-time error.

Answer (score 9):

From the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/index.html), Java SE 8 Edition, [4.12.5 Initial Values of Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5):

> A local variable (§14.4, §14.14) must be explicitly given a value before it is used, by either initialization (§14.4) or assignment (§15.26), in a way that can be verified using the rules for definite assignment (§16 (Definite Assignment)).

Answer (score 6):

Local variables don't get initialized.

This is a local variable:

```
void aaa() {
    int x;
}
```

This is an instance variable. These *do* get initialized automatically:

```
class X {
    int x;
}
```

Comment: @Mansuro: also for array contents.

Comment: static variables get intitialized also...As far as I know, it's like this: only local variables don't get intitialized. And array contents are automatically initialized.

Comment: if array contents are automatically initialized, why is there a NullPointerException when trying to access an element by index?

Comment: @Mansuro - That only happens with an array of reference types, because reference type variables default to `null`. Try instantiating an `int[8]` - each element will be `0`.

Comment: an instance Object variable will also get initialized to null

Answer (score 3):

**Data Type Default Value (for fields)**

byte    0

short   0

int 0

long    0L

float   0.0f

double  0.0d

char    ‘u0000’

String (or any object)  null

boolean false

Comment: But the question was: *"Why does Eclipse show an error telling me the variable may not have been initialized?"*

Comment: If a declared variable is a class member, they will get default values, however, local variables don't get default values, thus Eclipse shows that error @PeterMortensen

Comment: That ought to be in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the *Primitive Data Types* reference provided by you:

> "Local variables are slightly different; the compiler never assigns a default value to an uninitialized local variable. If you cannot initialize your local variable where it is declared, make sure to assign it a value before you attempt to use it. Accessing an uninitialized local variable will result in a compile-time error".

Comment: This is almost exactly the same as [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9687634/variable-default-value-in-java/9687671#9687671) (though there is only a 53 seconds difference, so you are excused).

Answer (score -4):

What you see is not an error, but your Eclipse preference. You can change it to ignore uninitialized variables in Eclipse preference.