# use of unassigned local variables in code

Tags: c#, .net

I have declared three variables namely

```
TemplateData tData; TaskInstance tInstance;int tID;
```

in my program. Though I have clearly declared them, I keep getting an error "Use of unassigned local variable" 
I am completely baffled as to why my compiler is giving this error.

Comment: It's not complaining that you haven't *declared* them. It's complaining that you haven't *assigned* to them.

Comment: Well as the error says you have not assigned any value

Comment: As for *why* the compiler requires you to assign them, [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931226/are-c-sharp-uninitalized-variables-dangerous/8933935#8933935)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Compiler is absolutely correct`. Although you have declared them but Compiler did not tells you that "Use of **undeclared** local variable". It tells you `"Use of unassigned local variable"`..

**There is difference between declaration and assignments of variables**...

Assign the values to variables. In your code it should be

```
TemplateData tData = null;
TaskInstance tInstance = null;
int tID = 0;
```

OR

```
TemplateData tData = new TemplateData();
TaskInstance tInstance = new TaskInstance();
int tID = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have **declared** them but you have not **assigned a value** to them. You must, as a minimum, assign a value of `null` before you can use those variables, otherwise you would be passing an undefined value to `ProcessInput`.

Answer (score 0):

You have not assigned a value to the variables. that's what the compiler error says. It says "use of unassigned local variable". Note the difference between **declaring** and **assigning** a variable. Just set them all to `null` or 0 (or some other appropriate default value) before using them:

```
TemplateData tData = null;
TaskInstance tInstance = null;
int tID = 0;
```

The compiler complains because using a variable without assigning it some value before can often be the cause of bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize these values prior to passing them in a method:

```
   TemplateData tData = new TemplateData();                 
   TaskInstance tInstance = new TaskInstance();                 
   int tID = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

just initialize those variables;

```
TemplateData tData = null; TaskInstance tInstance = null; int tID = 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

You should always assign default or null values when u declare vars.

```
            TemplateData tData = null;
            TaskInstance tInstance = null;
            int tID = 0;
```