# Strange behaviour of switch case with boolean value

Tags: c#, .net, boolean, switch-statement

My question is not about how to solve this error(I already solved it) but why is this error with boolean value.

My function is

```
private string NumberToString(int number, bool flag)
{
    string str;

    switch(flag)
    {
        case true: 
            str = number.ToString("00");
            break;
        case false:
            str = number.ToString("0000"); 
            break;
    }

    return str;
}
```

Error is `Use of unassigned local variable 'str'`. Bool can only take true or false. So it will populate `str` in either case. Then why this error?

Moreover this error is gone if along with true and false case I add a `default` case, but still what can a bool hold apart from true and false?

Why this strange behaviour with bool variable?

Comment: I don't think the compiler takes the type's possible values into account when checking for definite assignment inside a `switch` statement. In other words, you would get the same error if `flag` was an `int` and you had 4,294,967,296 `case` statements ranging from `-2,147,483,648` to `2,147,483,647`.

Comment: It could be `null` I guess `bool? flag = null;`

Comment: The same question has been asked before, looking for duplicate now.

Comment: Is this a runtime error or a compile error or warning? Try string str = "";

Comment: I guess the compiler simply is not smart enough to recognize that you have cases for all possible values in your select statement. Initialize str by using 'string str = "";' should help.

Comment: And Bali is right, bool cannot just be true or false but also null.

Comment: @BaliC: I have bool and not bool?. Bool is value type so cannot take null.

Comment: @Ollie: My question is not about how to solve this error(I already solved it) but why is this error with boolean value. and Moreover who said bool can be null. bool? can be null but not bool. Its a value type and not reference type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error you get is about `string` variable and **not** `boolean` possible values.

The fact that there is **no way** that noone of `cases` run, is a true (in this case), but compiler doesn't go so far in analyzing the code. It just looks on variable that is not assigned and used in some conditions and there is not default one, so **suppose** that there *could* be some case when it remains unassigned.

Answer (score 9):

Writing a switch statement on a boolean variable seems kinda wasty to me. Why not use the conditional operator ([`?:`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)):

```
private string NumberToString(int number, bool flag)
{
    return flag ? number.ToString("00") : number.ToString("0000"); 
}
```

The code seems a bit more concise and you don't need local variables.

But back to your question about why your code doesn't compile => it is because variables must always be assigned and this assignment should not happen inside conditional statements.

Comment: You said assignment should not happen inside conditional statements. Right? Wrong. Add a default case conditional statement and it will not give error.

Comment: Yes, adding a default case statement would indeed fix the error. But as I said, writing a switch statement with true, false and default cases seems absolutely insane and a good candidate for thedailywtf.com :-)

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal: It's to keep it as simple as possible for the compiler and also to prevent the programmer from simple bugs. So if you show that  you've thought a little bit about it(default case), the compiler allows it.

Comment: What if there was more lines of code inside switch case? What you have provided is an alternative and not an explanation to cause.

Comment: I guess that's because of your oversimplified example. If there are other lines, simply use `if/else` with boolean variables, not switches. With if/else you don't need to worry about assigning as well and you have one less thing to worry about => the default case which doesn't make any sense with boolean variables.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal: You can find the explanation at the end of [Eric Lipperts answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8933935/284240). _"The reason this is illegal in C# is because using an unassigned local has high likelihood of being a bug. We simply make it illegal, and then the compiler prevents you from ever having such a bug."_

Comment: Or even better: `return number.ToString(flag ? "00" : "0000")` :)

Answer (score 4):

I think, you are trying to ask, why `str` variable is unassigned, as the switch statement's cases will assign it some value, but the compiler can't determine whether it will fall in any of the case statement, That is why you are getting this error on returning `str`.

If you add a default case with string assignment, then the compiler will know for sure that, the str will hold some value and that is why you don't get error

Comment: But bool always holds a value as it is value type.

Comment: yes, but the C# compiler doesn't take that into account, I am trying to find an official source for that, will post it as soon as I find it

Comment: I think Tim Schmelter just posted it. stackoverflow.com/a/8933935/284240

Answer (score 3):

```
private string NumberToString(int number, bool flag)
{
    string str = "";

    switch(flag)
    {
        case true: 
            str = number.ToString("00");
            break;
        case false:
            str = number.ToString("0000"); 
            break;
    }

    return str;
}
```

**write this** `string str = "";` - you should assign value

if you add default case there is no chance to fall through the switch cases without assigning. Now it is

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's been good explanation for causes of this issue, but there is one more solution to the problem, which was not mentioned. Just put `default` instead of second `case`:

```
    private string NumberToString(int number, bool flag)
    {
        string str;

        switch (flag)
        {
            case true:
                str = number.ToString("00");
                break;
            default:
                str = number.ToString("0000");
                break;
        }

        return str;
    }
```

It leaves compiler with no further thoughts about `flag` variable value as we always assign a `default` value in our `switch` statement.

Also consider if-else statement equivalent solution:

```
    private string NumberToString(int number, bool flag)
    {
        string str;

        if (flag)
            str = number.ToString("00");
        else
            str = number.ToString("0000");

        return str;
    }
```

I am not particularly fond of 'one-liners' (one line solutions), as they lack extendability and moreover - readability, but as the last resort just use ternary operators like this:

```
    private string NumberToString(int number, bool flag)
    {
        return flag ? number.ToString("00") : number.ToString("0000");
    }
```

While I am at it - consider using extension method + defaulting boolean to `false`, for example:

```
public static class intExtensions
{
    public static string NumberToString(this int number, bool flag = false)
    {
        return flag ? number.ToString("00") : number.ToString("0000");
    }
}
```

and then in main class:

```
        int intVal = 56;
        string strVal1 = intVal.NumberToString(true);
        string strVal2 = intVal.NumberToString();
```