# in C#, why do I see there's a zero stored in my int variable when I declare it, but still get an error saying I should initialize it?

Tags: c#, variables

in C#, if i do something like:

```
int x;
```

then hit F10, I see that there's a zero stored in x.

but when i try to use x, it tells me that i should initialize it .. 
why is that ?
there's supposed to be a zero there, right ?

the same thing is also true about arrays, so:

```
int[]a = new int[5];
```

if we F10 that, we'll see that all the ints in there are zeros..

What's going on ?
and why should i ever MUST initialize a variable in C# unlike in C++ ?

Comment: Because that's what the compiler expects it's not interpreted like VB and if this is a local variable I would definitely recommend initializing it to zero.. it's best to not assume
When I initialize string I always initialize the variable to string.Empty and int's to 0

Comment: By F10 you mean Visual Studio debugger behaviour?

Comment: `0` is the default value of `integer`. You could better initialize to a specific value.

Comment: yes by F10 I mean debugging in Visual Studio.

Comment: @VeXe I deleted my answer cause cannot replicated x having ? in it instead of 0 as default. So is your second question question on this sort of syntax int? x;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a compile time error trying to help you reduce bugs in your code due to un-initialized variables.  Very useful.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y7h161d(VS.80).aspx

More reading:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2005/11/08/490248.aspx

Some words on disabling the error (you can't just to warn you - it's not a warning):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharplanguage/thread/a073ccea-c43b-4536-be76-41949f0e2135

and

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/12/absence-of-evidence-is-not-evidence-of-absence.aspx 
(proves to be most informative on the subject)

and even [more](http://blog.liranchen.com/2010/07/behind-locals-init-flag.html) discussing relationship between "localsinit" IL flag (that forces default values to be set for locals) and its relation to "double assignment" (C# forces you to write `int v=0` even if it is already there). And if you want to read even deeper - "localsinit" defined in section I.12.2 of [ECMA-335 available here](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm).

Comment: Incomplete answer. Some variables in C# are indeed initialized to a default value (such as static variables, or instance variables). On the other hand, local variables are not initialized to a default value.

Comment: Even more reading : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931226/are-c-sharp-uninitalized-variables-dangerous/8933935#8933935 from Eric Lippert

Comment: considering that the error code for the uninitialized problem is CS0165, can I disable it ?

Comment: You'd be far better off just initializing your local variables rather than disabling compiler errors.

Comment: @ChristopherBerman, all local variables *are* initialized to 0 by run-time due to C# setting "localsinit" flag to force memory allocated for local variables to be set to 0. It is compiler that (rightfully in my opinion)  insists on initialization.

Comment: Good point. The distinction between 'initialized' and 'assigned'.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Without wanting to be a nasty pedant, that's not quite true; Creating a new local string will not be initialised to 0, it will be null; but you're absolutely correct that the runtime should insist on initialisation.

Comment: @RussC, Not sure what is not quite true: string is reference type - the space for variable is initialized with 0 which represents `null` pointer.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov indeed, hence my apology for being pedantic;  but that's just a conformity if you create a new string 'str' and test is 'str == 0', it won't compile but testing uf 'str == null' will.

Comment: The Eric Lippert blog linked in this answer is a very good way of explaining this compiler error.

Answer (score 4):

Simply put, because that's the way C# works. From the C# Language Specification:

> 5.3.2 Initially unassigned variables
>
> The following categories of variables are classified as initially unassigned:
>
> · Instance variables of initially unassigned struct variables.
>
> · Output parameters, including the this variable of struct instance constructors.
>
> · Local variables, except those declared in a catch clause or a foreach statement.

On the other hand:

> 5.3.1 Initially assigned variables
>
> The following categories of variables are classified as initially assigned:
>
> ·         Static variables.
>
> ·         Instance variables of class instances.
>
> ·         Instance variables of initially assigned struct variables.
>
> ·         Array elements.
>
> ·         Value parameters.
>
> ·         Reference parameters.
>
> ·         Variables declared in a catch clause or a foreach statement.

Answer (score 3):

Simple... because the compiler insists that you initialize local variables before using them. This prevents a whole category of mistakes associated with failure to initialize.

If you look at the IL generated from the following few statements:

```
int x;
Console.WriteLine("hello");
int y=5;
x=6;
Console.WriteLine(x+y);
```

you see the following:

```
//notice no ops related to x prior to console.writeline
IL_0000:  ldstr       "hello"
IL_0005:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_000A:  ldc.i4.5    
IL_000B:  stloc.1        //create/store y
IL_000C:  ldc.i4.6    
IL_000D:  stloc.0        //x is really only created right here
IL_000E:  ldloc.0     
IL_000F:  ldloc.1     
IL_0010:  add         
IL_0011:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
```

if you're seeing a value for x prior to it's storing in IL, then it's a debugger trick.

Comment: And a misleading trick at that. Weird that the debugger wouldn't draw the distinction.

Comment: Well, I suppose the debugger has a notion of the name associated with each local, so displays whatever ldloc.[index of x] dumps on the stack, even before it is initially stored/"declared" in IL.

Answer (score 2):

The auto-initialization is a runtime security feature I believe, not a language guarantee. It happens that .NET zeroes variables, but that doesn't have to be true with every framework.

Note that for arrays, it **is** guaranteed.

Comment: so for arrays, there's not luck about it, there will be zeros everytime right ?
but why is that ?
I mean, arrays are just a bunch of adjacent-same type variables,
so an array of 10 ints is just 10 ints, shouldn't we treat each one of them with the same treatment as we did with a single int ?

Comment: It have to be 0 filled for all *compliant* implementations of  CLI (like .Net Framework).

Comment: @VeXe: That's a language design question -- what you say is basically what they do in C++, but I don't know why they did it differently in C#. It's just how the language is designed; you can't work around it. (They possibly did it this way just because it's handy, or because they don't like undefined values, but I don't know the actual reason.) Also, note that it's *much harder* (if not impossible) for the compiler to verify if you've assigned to an array member -- so it would need to either leave them with unspecified values, or just initialize them. They chose the latter.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: No kidding! That's like saying "only non-criminals have to obey the law". Kind of true by definition, isn't it? :P

Answer (score 1):

It being 0 is just luck, it could be anything, that is why you must initialize it.

Comment: ok, this means that it could be something else right ?
but in both cases there will be something stored in it, 
whether it's a zero or not, so when I use it, it has something stored in it, so ... ?

Comment: Default values are well defined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx).  A [nullable type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=vs.100).aspx) provides an explicit means of indicating a value is not present.

Comment: What do default values have to do with this?  The OP did not say he was using a boxed object so no `new` is involved.

Comment: 0 is not just luck, but it may or may not be "default" for your type. 0 is because C# sets "localsinit" flag for each method and run-time respects it: "If the localsinit flag on the method is true, the block of memory returned is
initialized to 0; otherwise, the initial value of that block of memory is unspecified" (III.3.47 of ECMA 335).