# Binary search algorithm turns up error - Use of unassigned local variable

Tags: c#, algorithm, variables, unsigned

I was following a tutorial showing how to create a Binary search algorithm from scratch. However I recieve the error "Use of unassigned local variable 'Pivot'". I'm new to the language and have only tried much simpler languages previously.

I apologise for the lack of internal documentation and appauling use of white space.

The error is near the bottom of the code labled using "//"

Here is the program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Binary_Search_2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] arr = new int[10];

            Random rnd = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = rnd.Next(1, 10);
            }

            Array.Sort(arr);
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0},", arr[i]);
            }
            int Start = 0;
            int End = arr.Length;
            int Center = Start + End / 2;

            int Pivot;

            while (arr[6] > 0)
            {
                while (arr[6] < arr[Center])
                {
                    End = Center;
                    Center = (End + Start) / 2;
                    if (Pivot == arr[Center])
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("The Index is {0}", arr[Center]);
                    }
                    break; 
                }

                while (arr[6] > arr[Center])
                {
                    Start = Center;
                    Center = (End + Start) / 2;
                    if (Pivot == arr[Center])  //**This is where the error occurs.** 
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("The index is {0}", arr[Center]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sorry if this is actually something really simple but I don't have anyone to teach me directly and I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Change the line `int Pivot;` to `int Pivot = 0;`.

Comment: FYI, there is a built-in BinarySearch function.

Comment: If you're following a tutorial, perhaps including a *link* to the tutorial would help us?

Comment: And it is usually good to look at 3 sources at the very least, to cross references and make sure that one of them isn't completely stupid.

Comment: Thank you very much :] I have created programs using the built in Binary Search but I wanted to learn how to create one from scratch as well just for the theory.

Comment: What could be simpler than c# ;-)

Comment: seems a bit silly doing a binary search if you have to sort the data first.

Comment: @Jodrell If you know that you're probably going to be doing several binary searches, you can sort it once and its totally worth it.

Comment: @YoryeNathan, as long as you are searching for different items.

Comment: @Jodrell You will usually look for different items more than you look for the same one.

Comment: @Jodrell Simpler then C#? Ever tried Real Basic :P Ahh those were the days.

Comment: @MatthewMorgan, I consider myself harmed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is caused by this line:

```
int Pivot;
```

The value of `Pivot` needs to be set before using it in an `if` statement.

This indicates an error in your code: you check `Pivot''s value in an`if` statement, but you never assign to it. Look through the tutorial to find a line that looks like this:

```
Pivot = ... // <<=== some expression here
```

Most likely, you did not enter this line into your program when you followed the tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for the help, that was indeed the problem. First time posting on this website and I'm quite amazed, I get several answers within minutes :D

Comment: @MatthewMorgan You are welcome! If any of the answers provided the information that you were looking for, you can accept that answer by clicking the grey check mark outline next to it. This will indicate to others that you are not longer actively looking for an improved solution, and earn you a brand-new badge on Stack Overflow. P.S. Welcome to the site!

Comment: Thanks, will do. Hope to have you answer my kinda dumn programming problems again some time!

Comment: @MatthewMorgan - For a more complete answer, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/11462643/21727 .  For example, if Pivot was an instance variable of your Program class, then you would not need to initialize it.  However, since it is a local variable in your Main method, it does need to be initialized.

Answer (score 2):

**Binary Search explained:**

The general problem is simply finding a specific element in a bunch of elements.
Binary search does that by cutting "vision" in halves until finding the element, or finding out that it does not exist. By checking the center of the current view of vision, you can tell if the element is on the left or the right, but for that, the elements must be sorted.

**Example in theory (element exists):**

Lets say we are looking for `1` in this array of elements:

```
0, 1, 4, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10
```

In each step, we mark our vision field, and it's center like so:

> - S = start of vision field
> - E = end of vision field
> - M = middle of vision field = (S + E + 1) / 2

```
S           M        E
0, 1, 4, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10
```

Value in M is 6, which is bigger than 1, so we know that the 1 is on M's left. Therefore, we set E to be M-1 and recalculate M:

```
S     M  E
0, 1, 4, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10
```

Value in M is now 4 - still bigger than 1, so we go further left:

```
   M
S  E
0, 1, 4, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10
```

Value in M is now 1, which is the value we were looking for, so we're done!

**Example in theory (element does not exists):**

Lets say we are looking for `5` in this array of elements:

```
0, 1, 4, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10
```

In each step, we mark our vision field, and it's center like so:

> - S = start of vision field
> - E = end of vision field
> - M = middle of vision field = (S + E + 1) / 2

```
S           M        E
0, 1, 4, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10
```

Value in M is 6, which is bigger than 5, so we know that the 5 is on M's left. Therefore, we set E to be M-1 and recalculate M:

```
S     M  E
0, 1, 4, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10
```

Value in M is now 4, which is smaller than 5, so we know that the 5 must be on M's right. Therefore, we set S to be M+1 and recalculate M:

```
         S
         E
         M
0, 1, 4, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10
```

Value in M is now 4, which is smaller than 5, so we should go further right again, but oops! S=E means that if we go any where furthermore, they will cross each other, meaning we've already looked there, so the element surely does not exist, and the search is terminated.

**Psuedo Code + explanations:**

```
arr = 0, 1, 4, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10;
wanted = 5; // Holds the value to look for
index = -1; // Will hold the index of the found value (-1 means not found)

s = 0; // Initialize S with the beginning of all array
e = arr.Length - 1; // Initialize E with the last element of the array

// As long as we don't cross ourselves
while (s <= e)
{
    // Calculate M (rounded)
    m = (s + e + 1) / 2;

    // Get the current middle value
    curr = arr[m];

    // Check to see if we found our wanted value
    if (curr == wanted)
    {
        index = m;
        break;
    }
    else if (curr < wanted)
    {
        // Wanted value is further to the right
        s = m + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        // Wanted value is further to the left
        e = m - 1;
    }
}

// Here, if index is -1, the wanted value does not exist in arr.
// Otherwise, it holds it's index.
```

**C# generic code:**

```
public int BinarySearch<T>(this ICollection<T> elements, T item) where T : IComparable
{
    // Assumes that elements is already sorted!

    var s = 0;
    var e = elements.Count - 1;

    while (s <= e)
    {
        var m = (s + e + 1) / 2;

        var cmp = elements[m].CompareTo(item);

        switch (cmp)
        {
            case -1:
                s = m + 1;
                break;
            case 1:
                e = m - 1;
                break;
            default:
                return m;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
int[] nums = ...;
List<double> doubles = ...;
SortedSet<People> people = ...; // People compared by ID

var i0 = nums.Sort().ToArray().BinarySearch(5);
doubles.Sort();
var i2 = doubles.BinarySearch(5.3d);
var i3 = people.BinarySearch(new People{ID = 5});
```

Comment: Thanks you so much, it's extremely helpful having this explained so well, my current computing teacher doesn't know any of this material so I have been a little puzzled :]

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigning any value to the Pivot variable after declaring it. When evaluating it in the if statement it is still not initialized.