# Why are non-initialized value types not allowed?

Tags: c#

The C# compiler rejects the use of an un-assigned int. However using an int via a class is not forbidden. Why that difference? And why not allow the use of un-initialized variables as they are guaranteed to be zero?

```
class Program
{
    class MyInt { public int I; }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyInt mi = new MyInt();
        Console.WriteLine(mi.I);// accepted by the compiler
        int i;
        Console.WriteLine(i); // rejected by the compiler
    }
}
```

Comment: You want 'The spec says it's forbidden' answer, or do you want to know why the decision was made to ban that kind of usages?

Comment: This one gives you the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8933935/1163867

Comment: @Rawling, This is definitely not a duplicate. The other answer doesn't provide explanation as to why instance fields are indeed considered as initialized.

Comment: Non-initialized value types are allowed under some circumstances, for example in combination with an out parameter reference.

Comment: @haim770 http://stackoverflow.com/a/8933935/251311

Comment: @haim770 Whatever. The best answer you're going to get is "because the spec says so". I'm not sure how many different variations of that question/answer we need.

Comment: @Rawling There is an answer provided by Eric (the one I linked to closing as duplicate), who was on C# team at Microsoft for quite a long time.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Yeah I like that one, but I blew my Mjolnir usage too soon :)

Comment: Shit, I had a 4 paragraph answer and I thought it could add value.

Comment: @Rawling i've seen some questions that are marked as multiple duplicates. Maybe you are able to mark it as duplicate again (or are maybe those questions simply edited to contain the multiple duplicates)?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer you can probably add it to the duplicated questions.

Comment: @Default I can't do that - I think those are questions that got five  votes to close as duplicate but for different questions. Marcin's choice is better than mine was anyway.

Comment: I'm not agree to mark this question as duplicate. The question is about a difference and the linked answer do not talk about the difference between local variables and class member.

Comment: @Default I'm not sure if it would add actual value my answer. It was a speculation