# What is the reason for "Use of unassigned local variable" error?

Tags: c#, .net, boolean, default, default-value

With this code:

```
bool dataToAdd;
if (null == _priceComplianceDetailList) return dataToAdd;
```

I was getting a compiler error, "*Use of unassigned local variable 'dataToAdd'*"

So I had to explicitly assign "false" to the bool:

```
bool dataToAdd = false;
if (null == _priceComplianceDetailList) return dataToAdd;
```

In context:

```
private bool PopulateSheetWithDetailData()
{
    bool dataToAdd = false;
    if (null == _priceComplianceDetailList) return dataToAdd;
    List<PriceComplianceDetail> _sortedDetailList =
    . . .
    return _sortedDetailList.Count > 0;
}
```

Why is it necessary? Don't bools have a default value of false?

Comment: The default only applies to class members, local variables in methods must be explicitly assigned.

Comment: Also you can remove completely the variable since you are returning based on the count of the list and in the first if block you can return false directly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because local variables aren't initialized by default. You should initialized them explicitly. It is a compiler feature to avoid future mistakes. It is clarified in language specification [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691172(v=VS.71).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691170(v=vs.71).aspx).

> The reason this is illegal in C# is because using an unassigned local
>   has high likelihood of being a bug

If you want to know the reason for this decision see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931226/are-c-sharp-uninitalized-variables-dangerous/8933935#8933935).

Comment: Also relevant is [section 5.1.7](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691170(v=vs.71).aspx). Specifically: "A local variable introduced by a _local-variable-declaration_ is not automatically initialized and thus has no default value."

Comment: Added to the answer, Thanks @JoeFarrell,