# How do I properly call this method in my main program?

Tags: c#

This is a BMI calculator, that calculates either imperial or metric BMI based on what option the user chooses. I then need to display their BMI status (underweight, overweight, obese). I have a method in my Person class that I want to call in the main method, but Visual Studio underlines the bmi variable and says "use of unassigned local variable"

How can I fix the variable problem?

Here is the class code:

```
class Person
{
    double Height { get; set; }
    double Weight { get; set; }
    double Inches { get; set; }
    double Bmi { get; set; }

    public Person()
    {

    }

    public Person(double height, double weight, double bmi)
    {
        Height = height;
        Weight = weight;
        Bmi = bmi;
    }

    public Person (double height, double weight, double inches, double bmi)
    {
        Height = height;
        Weight = weight;
        Inches = inches;
        Bmi = bmi;
    }


    //calculates BMI using metric formula 
    public static double CalcMetric(double height, double weight)
    {
        double bmi = weight / Math.Pow(height, 2);
        return bmi;
    }

    //calculates BMI using imperial formula
    public static double CalcImperial(double height, double weight)
    {
        double bmi = weight / Math.Pow(height, 2) * 703;
        return bmi;
    }

    public void Status(double bmi)
    {
        if (bmi < 18.5)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your BMI status is underweight.");
        }
        else
          if (bmi < 24.9)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your BMI status is normal.");
        }
        else
          if (bmi < 29.9)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your BMI status is overweight.");
        }
        else
          if (bmi > 30)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your BMI status is obese.");
        }
    }

}
}
```

Here is the main program

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White; //set background
        Console.Clear();
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black; //set foreground

        string inputHeight;
        string inputWeight;
        string aValue;
        double choice;
        double height;
        double weight;
        double bmi;


        Person p = new Person();

        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to BMI Calculator. \nEnter 1 for imperial calculator, 2 for metric calculator or 3 to quit.");
        aValue = Console.ReadLine();
        choice = double.Parse(aValue);

        if (choice == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter height in inches: ");
            inputHeight = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter weight in lbs: ");
            inputWeight = Console.ReadLine();

            height = double.Parse(inputHeight);
            weight = double.Parse(inputWeight);

            Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is: " + Person.CalcImperial(height, weight));
        }
        else
                if (choice == 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter height in meters: ");
            inputHeight = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter weight in kilos: ");
            inputWeight = Console.ReadLine();

            height = double.Parse(inputHeight);
            weight = double.Parse(inputWeight);

            Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is: " + Person.CalcMetric(height, weight));
        }
        else
                if (choice == 3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Goodbye!");
        }

        p.Status(bmi);



        Console.ReadKey();

            }



        }
```

Comment: you can simply remove variable declaration of `double bmi`;

Comment: Unrelated: `double` for the choice? Looks odd to me.

Comment: Don't want to use a decimal or a float

Comment: How about `int`? You won't have a choice 1.5 , will you?

Comment: Why would I use an int, I am not working with integers

Comment: Not right now. But how is that related to `choice` 's type?

Comment: is that worked for you ??

Comment: sorry did not realize you were talking about `choice `

Answer (score 1):

you are getting error because  `double bmi;` is not initialized. As per guide line method member need to be initialized in method you cannot just declare it. so you need to do like this

```
double bmi=0;
```

check this : [Are C# uninitialized variables dangerous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931226/are-c-sharp-uninitialized-variables-dangerous/8933935#8933935)

---

there is one more issue in your code ,

```
//in your person class
public void Status(double bmi)
{
}
```

and you are doing   `p.Status(ref bmi);`, you will not get updated value as double is value type change done in function not reflect actual value , you need to do like this ,

```
//in your person class
public void Status(ref double bmi)
{
}
```

with help of ref you will get value back from functio.

---

even better solution is to return value from function

```
//in your person class
public double Status()
{
     double bmi=0;
    //rest of code 
    return bmi;
}
```

in main `bmi = p.Status();`

Comment: Now I cannot get the value of BMI to change from zero

Comment: How are you trying? Definitely not in the snippet from the question. @MariahM. (Hint: There should be `bmi = Person.CalcMetric|Imperial( h,w);` somewhere ...

Comment: @MariahM. - check my update, you either have to use `ref` or return value from function

Comment: Trying to call it using p.Status(bmi); And that sounds like something I would put in the setter. Will try

Comment: @MariahM. - just one update you need to do like this `p.Status(ref bmi);` and in method also you need `ref` as given in update

Answer (score 0):

Bmi is a internal member(by default) of person class so you can not use the BMI directly instead use

```
Status(CalcMetric); or `status(CalcImperial);` *according to your requirement*
```

So that these function return the value of BMI during the function call.