# How to Set multiple Variables value in one Line in C#?

Tags: c#

I define this variables in my code, I want to initialize them in one step, how can I do this?

```
int currentYearSavingDays, currentYearSavingXMins, currentYearSavingNXMins, currentYearUsedDays, currentYearUsedXMins, yearLimitRemainingDays, yearLimitRemainingXMins, totalYearlyDays, totalYearlyXMins, totalSavingDays, totalSavingMins, totalUsableDays, totalUsableMins, nextYearTotalUsableDays, nextYearTotalUsableMins, dayWorkMinutes, previousYearRemainingDays, previousYearRemainingMins;
```

forExample:

```
currentYearSavingDays, currentYearSavingXMins, currentYearSavingNXMins, currentYearUsedDays, currentYearUsedXMins, yearLimitRemainingDays, yearLimitRemainingXMins, totalYearlyDays, totalYearlyXMins, totalSavingDays, totalSavingMins, totalUsableDays, totalUsableMins, nextYearTotalUsableDays, nextYearTotalUsableMins, dayWorkMinutes, previousYearRemainingDays, previousYearRemainingMins = 0;
```

Comment: `currentYearSavingDays = currentYearSavingXMins = .... = 0`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best I know is this.

```
int currentYearSavingDays, currentYearSavingXMins, currentYearSavingNXMins, currentYearUsedDays, currentYearUsedXMins, yearLimitRemainingDays, yearLimitRemainingXMins, totalYearlyDays, totalYearlyXMins, totalSavingDays, totalSavingMins, totalUsableDays, totalUsableMins, nextYearTotalUsableDays, nextYearTotalUsableMins, dayWorkMinutes, previousYearRemainingDays, previousYearRemainingMins;
currentYearSavingDays = currentYearSavingXMins = currentYearSavingNXMins = currentYearUsedDays = currentYearUsedXMins = yearLimitRemainingDays = yearLimitRemainingXMins = totalYearlyDays = totalYearlyXMins = totalSavingDays = totalSavingMins = totalUsableDays = totalUsableMins = nextYearTotalUsableDays = nextYearTotalUsableMins = dayWorkMinutes = previousYearRemainingDays = previousYearRemainingMins = 0;
```

Answer (score 6):

I would frown upon the attempt to declare them all at once.  In addition to being ugly to read, it is not necessary.

Instead, this seems like a great candidate for a set of fields for a [class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes) or [struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/structs).

In C#, [value type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types) fields are allocated and automatically initialized to their default value by the [memory manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/automatic-memory-management).  So, in this particular case, if you had created a new class/struct for just these values, then you wouldn't have to explicitly initialize them.

Note that you could simply leave them as fields in the current class as well, so long as you're careful not to violate the [single responsibility principle](https://hackernoon.com/you-dont-understand-the-single-responsibility-principle-abfdd005b137).

Also note that the strategy described in this answer will not work if these are [local variables](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/20461/local-variable-c). As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8933935/1472222) explains, while the initialization semantics are the same, use of uninitialized local variables is generally a bug and is not allowed in C#.  In that case, it would be better, in my opinion, to declare and initialize each variable on its own line.

Comment: Yup...I agree. " ...declare and initialize each variable on its own line."

Answer (score 1):

You can declare and initialize like this:

```
int one = 1, two = 2, three = 3;
```

The variable initialization is optional

This Line...

```
int one,two,three;
```

...would have all the variables set to zero (default integer value).

[Variables Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/variables)