# How to await conditional asych task

Tags: c#, async-await

I have an asynchronous task that is conditional.
I want to await it if it's called, but, obviously, not wait for it if it's not.

This is what I tried.

```
Task l;

if(condition)
{
    l = MyProcessAsync();
}

//do other stuff here

if(condition)
{
    await Task.WhenAll(l); //unassigned variable error
}
```

I get `Use of unassigned local variable 'l'` compiler error.

What's the appropriate way to do this?

Comment: `Task l = null;` or `Task l = Task.CompletedTask;`

Comment: Thanks! Why not put it as the answer?

Comment: Didn't have time to add some description ATM =)

Comment: Note: you need to be *really really careful* with this approach; this is inherently concurrent; if `MyProcessAsync` is **completely unrelated** to anything in "do other stuff here", then you might get away with it, but this is the equivalent to starting a worker thread for half the code: if it touches any of the same objects, there could be major problems

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example, you have not assigned to `Task l;`.

You need to at least assign it to null.

Here is a working sample in a console application:

```
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var condition = true;
        Task task = null;

        if (condition)
        {
            task = MyProcessAsync();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Do other stuff");

        if (task != null)
        {
            await task;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Finished");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static async Task MyProcessAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("After async process");
    }
```

Outputs:

> Do other stuff
> After async process
> Finished

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know C# does not analyze if conditions in `if` statement are the same. Next code will work cause actually there will not be any branching at all generated by [compiler](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0ATEBqAPgAQCYBGAWACh8AGAAn2IFYBuCi/AZjsJoGEaBvCjWF1O+FDQCyACgCUAoSKUBIfEhoAbFuQrKAlgDMa04gF5TxWbsHllyjTVN0kAOh4QAtgAcNMAC4wGGraygC+rLYA9JEYEDQQfgAWMFA0AM5+AK4GRsmwEfpGJuaW1rqqrgDqyQB2AIIaGtIaskw00Zk1AIZpaXoA5jWBNABuXVB6XcC+NClQ0Lrh5EpLoUA=):

```
Task l;
if (1==1) // or  if(true)
{
    l = Task.CompletedTask;
}
//do other stuff here
if (1==1) // or  if(true)
{
    await Task.WhenAll(l); //unassigned variable error
}
```

So in you code you need to initialize local variable, cause [using an unassigned local has high likelihood of being a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8933935/2501279) (also see [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/variables#local-variables) of specification), so you need to initialize it for example to `null` or `Task.CompletedTask`from the get-go:

```
Task l = null; // or Task l = Task.CompletedTask;
```

Comment: I like the idea of initializing it to `Task.CompletedTask` more than `null`. I think if we use `Task.CompletedTask` as default value we could even just await `l` without a huge performance penalty.