# Why does this if statement not intialize or update my variable?

Tags: c#, if-statement, initialization, declaration

I'm a bit confused about declaring variables and then initializing/assigning those variables in a code block such as an if statement, then using that variable in the rest of my code.

The following example fails to assign the result of num1 + num2 to "result" in the if statement if "result" is declared and not initialized beforehand.

```
        int num1 = 1;
        int num2 = 2;
        int result; //declared

        if (num1 == 1)
        {
            result = num1 + num2;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(result); //Use of unassigned local variable "result"
```

However, declaring and initializing "result" beforehand successfully updates the "result" value in the if statement.

```
        int num1 = 1;
        int num2 = 2;
        int result = 0; //declared and initialized

        if (num1 == 1)
        {
            result = num1 + num2;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(result); //3
```

Moreover, if I change the condition in the if statement simply to "true" instead of "num1 == 1", then both of the previous examples work perfectly.

Could someone kindly explain this to me?

Comment: This post could clearly answers your question IMO https://stackoverflow.com/a/8933935/2946329

Comment: Yes, thanks! It seems the C# compiler does't know if the code in the if statement will execute, so it must assign their default values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the compiler can't determine that `result` is initialized before using, it will fail with error CS0165 (Use of unassigned local variable).

Considering that `num1` is not a constant, compiler can't guarantee that it stays `1` after the initialization and `result = mu,1 + num2` will be executed. This example might look trivial, but it won't be difficult to change the code in a way that another thread can manipulate the values between the initialization of `num1` and the check. But when you change the condition to `true`, then the compiler can determine that `result` will always be initialized prior to the usage, hence it compiling.

Similarly, when `result` is initialized to zero at declaration, then again compiler has a guarantee that it is initialized prior to usage.