# Default values of local variables

Tags: java, variables

In Java, why do class variables get initialized to a default value? But local variables are not.

Comment: To prevent you from making mistakes.

Comment: To be explicit -- local variables are *always* given an explicit value before they're used. There is no need for a default value.

Comment: Check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415687/why-are-local-variables-not-initialized-in-java)

Comment: @AndyThomas You could make the same argument for instance variables, the "need" (or lack thereof) id arguably the same.

Comment: @DaveNewton - Except that the definite assignment constraint is not applied to non-final instance variables.

Comment: @AndyThomas Yes, but that doesn't provide reasoning, or change that the same arguments can be applied to surge instance or class variables.

Comment: @DaveNewton - That would be true if you *could* apply the definite assignment constraint to non-final instance variables. However, I question whether that's feasible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415687/why-are-local-variables-not-initialized-in-java

Comment: Better duplicate: *[Why are local variables not initialized in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415687)*

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The local variables are not initialized to default values, as in the case of class variables. The same applies to primitives and object references.

**JavaDoc (Section 4.12.5. Initial Values of Variables):**

> A local variable must be explicitly given a value before it is used, by either initialization or assignment, in a way that can be verified using the rules for definite assignment.

Comment: He knows this; the question is *why*.

Comment: Its the design of Java. If we can change Java architecture, which we can't, then we can change local variables to initialize to default values.

Comment: -1: Doesn't answer the question at all.