# Why does a String need to be initialized even if the assignment will happen later?

Tags: java, string, initialization

I get the "The local variable string may not have been initialized" error with the following code. The code itself doesn't make sense it was written just for the sake of exercise.

```
public class StringExercise
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String string; // initializing here fixes the issue
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            if( (i % 4) == 2 )
            {
                string = "Number: " + i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(string); // this is marked as wrong by Eclipse
    }
}
```

To get it working it is sufficient to initialize String as expressed in the comment above.

My question is why is it needed? The method `println` will never be given null and initialization will happen the first time the condition in the loop returns true. Am I doing something wrong or is it just Java being overcautious over programmer's errors? If the latter, how is it justified from the theoretical point of view?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415687/why-are-local-variables-not-initialized-in-java

Comment: Every Java local variable must be *guaranteed* to be assigned a value (even if only `null`) before it's referenced.

Comment: @BatScream I know it is not initialized, the question is different.

Comment: Every Java local variable must be *guaranteed* to be assigned a value (even if only null) before it's referenced.

Comment: This isn't to prevent stupid programmer errors, it's so that Java can guarantee it's own type safety.  There must be an assignment (of the same type) "visible" along *every* possible path to the point of reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My question is why is it needed?

Because even though your code is "logically" written so that `string` will indeed be initialized in the loop, the compiler doesn't know it. All it sees is:

```
for (loop; elements; here)
    if (someCondition)
        string = something;
```

In short: a compiler will not check the logic of your code; it it only smart enough as to check for syntax errors, but after that, the bytecode generation itself is "dumb".

And as Java requires that all variables be initialized before use, you get this compiler error.

Comment: But that wouldn't be a problem for a c++ compiler for example.

Comment: C++ (and C for that matter) has a different take on `auto` variables; if they are not initialized, they have a value which is not determined. Java _requires_ that local variables are initialized before use.

Comment: @HotLicks I am afraid I fail to understand the type safety aspect you mention; can you give an example?

Comment: Java must *guarantee* that the value arriving at, say, an operation that references a String is indeed a String.  This requires that the value be set along all paths.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler can't guarantee that `string = "Number: " + i;` will be executed within your `for` and `if`.