# returning a class type from an array

Tags: java

iv'e got a class here, called Classrooms, in my getTopStudent method, it's saying that my variable "topStudent" hasn't been initialized, something i'm missing?, not everything is explained in the videos in my AP java course

```
public class Classroom
{
    Student[] students;
    int numStudentsAdded;

    public Classroom(int numStudents)
    {
        students = new Student[numStudents];
        numStudentsAdded = 0;
    }

    public Student getTopStudent()
    {
        Student topStudent;
        for(int i = 1; i < students.length; i++)
        {

            if(students[i].getAverageScore() > students[i - 1].getAverageScore())
            {
                topStudent = students[i];
            }
            else
            {
                topStudent = students[i - 1];
            }

        }
        return topStudent;
    }

    public void addStudent(Student s)
    {
        students[numStudentsAdded] = s;
        numStudentsAdded++;
    }

    public void printStudents()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < numStudentsAdded; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(students[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

my student class is all working, nothing should be wrong with it, don't think it will be required to solve this.

tester:

```
public class ClassroomTester extends ConsoleProgram
{
    public void run()
    {
        Classroom c = new Classroom(2);

        Student ada = new Student("Ada", "Lovelace", 12);
        ada.addExamScore(44);
        ada.addExamScore(65);
        ada.addExamScore(77);

        Student alan = new Student("Alan", "Turing", 11);
        alan.addExamScore(38);
        alan.addExamScore(24);
        alan.addExamScore(31);

        // add students to classroom
        c.addStudent(ada);
        c.addStudent(alan);
        c.printStudents();

        Student topStudent = c.getTopStudent();
        System.out.println(topStudent);
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when `numStudents` is zero? `topStudent` is never going to be initialized then.

Comment: @reuseman or students.length = 1...

Comment: there are two students, numStudents will never be 0 or 1, ill edit and put the tester in

Comment: the only error with the problem is the return statement for my getTopStudent method, it just highlights that line and says "Classroom.java: Line 28: variable topStudent might not have been initialized"

Comment: @AllenHuskins `Classroom` doesn't know anything about `ClassroomTester` though. And there's nothing to prevent a `Classroom` from being created with an argument of zero or one. In order to be valid, the code has to *guarantee* that the value is initialized, even if you know that you only ever plan to call it with values greater than one.

Comment: Have you seen <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415687/why-are-local-variables-not-initialized-in-java>?. For more details please visit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should complain because if for loop in `getTopStudent()` never runs ,`topStudent` will remain uninitialized. use `Student topStudent  = null`

Comment: awesome c: that fixed my initialization problem, but now iv'e run into another, only changed the line to set topStudent to null, but my highschool is using a website called codeHS.com, and in the AP course it doesn't show what code it grades off of unless it can run, and i'm getting an error that says "you appear to be referencing an variable that is null", the code now runs on the tester, but it won't grade

Comment: fixed the referencing a null variable, instead of setting topStudent to null, i set it to students[0], which doesn't affect anything since the for loop runs and changes it to the correct student

Answer (score 0):

You may assume that the number of students to be greater than 1, but compiler detects that there is a  possibility of student object being un initialised in the case of students being 0. So the code you write should ensure that all flows are covered

You should probably have the code like this

```
public class Classroom
{
    Student[] students;
    int numStudentsAdded;

    public Classroom(int numStudents)
    {
        students = new Student[numStudents];
        numStudentsAdded = 0;
    }

    public Student getTopStudent()
    {
       if(students == null|| students.lenght ==0){
               return null;
        }          
        Student topStudent;
        for(int i = 1; i < students.length; i++)
        {

            if(students[i].getAverageScore() > students[i - 1].getAverageScore())
            {
                topStudent = students[i];
            }
            else
            {
                topStudent = students[i - 1];
            }

        }
        return topStudent;
}
```