# confusion about while loop

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm just starting to learn my first programming language as of yesterday, so I'm writing simple test programs from my java book.

What I'm attempting to do is to have a user enter a static monthly investment and how many months they will be saving for, then display their total savings after that period of time.

when I compile the program it says that in system.out.println at the end of the program that total has not been initialized. I have tried initializing total in just the loop but I figured that would put the scope of it in the loop So I tried initializing it at the top and figured it runs through the loop until the condition is met but doesn't go back to the top of the program to put the value back in so I make another variable at the end of the loop to hold the total at the end of the loop. What's Wrong with my logic

thank you for the help!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CompoundInterestSteadyRate {

public static void main(String[] args){ 
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


double monthlyInterestRate = (1 + 0.00417);

System.out.println("please enter amount saved each mounth");

double amountSavedMonthly = input.nextDouble();

System.out.println("please enter amount of months you will be saving for");
int amountOfMonthsSaved = input.nextInt();

int monthCountDown = amountOfMonthsSaved;

double totalAmount;
double addMonths;
double intitalAmount = 0;
while (monthCountDown > 0){

    addMonths = amountSavedMonthly * monthlyInterestRate + intitalAmount;

    intitalAmount = addMonths;

      totalAmount = intitalAmount;

}
double total = totalAmount;
System.out.println("your total after " + " " + amountOfMonthsSaved + " " + "months is:" + " " + "$" + total);
}
```

}

thanks everyone for the help it now compiles however it seems when going through the math it doesn't take in account the first month of savings for example if I do $100 each month its total at the end is %502.08 which I don't believe is right

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CompoundInterestSteadyRate {

public static void main(String[] args){ 
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


double monthlyInterestRate = (1 + 0.00417);

System.out.println("please enter amount saved each mounth");

double amountSavedMonthly = input.nextDouble();

System.out.println("please enter amount of months you will be saving for");
int amountOfMonthsSaved = input.nextInt();

int monthCountDown = amountOfMonthsSaved;

double totalAmount = 0;
double addMonths;
double intitalAmount = 0;
while (monthCountDown > 1){

    addMonths = amountSavedMonthly * monthlyInterestRate + intitalAmount;

    intitalAmount = addMonths;

      totalAmount = intitalAmount;

    monthCountDown = monthCountDown - 1;
}
double total = totalAmount;
System.out.println("your total after " + " " + amountOfMonthsSaved + " " + "months is:" + " " + "$" + total);
```

Comment: It would appear you have an infinite loop because the condition is always true

Comment: I just realized this and changed it to monthCOuntDown > 1 and then in the loop used a decrement for the variable however the original error that says total has not been initialized at the end still shows

Comment: Please [edit]  your question to include your latest changes.

Comment: That's not the right interest formula. It's that why it's not what you expected?

Answer (score 2):

set `totalAmount = 0,`that will instialize it, let me know if this fixes the problem

when you declare it declare it like this `double totalAmount = 0;`

Comment: thank you for this it did work the math isn't coming out right but that's my issue everything compiles.

Comment: anytime buddy, always available through email for further questions if you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is a little intricate although the compiler (`javac` program) provides following helpful message:

> Compound.java:33: error: variable totalAmount might not have been
>   initialized double total = totalAmount;

What could be happening you may wonder. The easy answer is to go to line 20 in your program and initialize the value of `totalAmount` to `0`. Then your program would compile.

The reason the compiler does that is rather complicated, but you can reason about it this way:

What if, just what if the `while` loop did not get run even once (as written, in your program, opposite is happening as you will soon figure out that you are forgetting something about the *loop variable*)? Then Java would execute the (next) statement `double total = totalAmount;` and the way this *assignment* statement is executed is roughly like this:

- read the variable on the right side of `=`, that is `totalAmount` in a temporary location
- transfer the contents of that location to the memory for the variable on the left side of `=`, i.e. `total`.

Now, [Java does not like to read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415687/why-are-local-variables-not-initialized-in-java) a *local* variable's (such as `totalAmount`) value that is never written to because it may contain some *garbage* value. When you initialize it with a value like `0`, this problem goes away.

Answer (score 1):

**try 2 steps:**

1. `double totalAmount;`  ==> `double totalAmount = 0;`
2. `while (monthCountDown > 0);` ==> `while (monthCountDown-- > 0);`

Hava a nice day, my friend.

Comment: Hi Okingniko, please try to use code formatting, it makes it easier for people to read your answer. Also, its useful to provide explanations to the OP, not just code. This way they, and any future readers, can learn the cause of the problem and not just the fix. Just wanted to let you know.

Answer (score 1):

First of all there is no need of using intitalAmount and totalAmount. Because each time you are inserting same values to them. Secondly if you make

```
monthCountdown > 1
```

then it will count a month less. Because suppose you are counting for 6 months. Now for monthCountdown > 1 the loop will iterate for 5 times and calculate interest for 5 times. Which I believe is not the logic you want to implement.
So it should be,

```
monthCountdown > 0
```

Lastly your mathematical logic is not correct because each time you are calculating the interest on the monthly value and adding it with the previous balance. But it should be like each time interest should be calculated on the total current balance.

```
while (monthCountDown > 0){    
        totalAmount = ( amountSavedMonthly + totalAmount ) * monthlyInterestRate;
}
```

Please let me know if any concern.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it isn't necessarily the case that `totalAmount` will not be initialized. However, depending on the user input, it is POSSIBLE that `totalAmount` will not have been initialized, which will then throw an exception when the program attempts to assign the value of `totalAmount` to `total`. To avoid this, you need to ensure that `totalAmount` gets initialized, which is easy to do. When you declare `totalAmount`, simply assign `0` as its value.

You also have a problem with your `while` loop. Because the value of `monthCountDown` is never changed within the loop, there is no way for the condition `monthCountDown > 0` to become `false`. I'm assuming you intended for `monthCountDown` to be reduced by 1 each time the loop is run, so you should include `monthCountDown--;` within the loop to prevent it from becoming an infinite loop.

Comment: thanks that's very logical and makes sense and that was what I intended to do and have corrected.

Answer (score 0):

cricket-007 is right about initializing totalamount = 0; But it looks like your `while` loop keeps going. Try this!

**changed your arrow key from > to <, on the while loop**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CompoundInterestSteadyRate {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        double monthlyInterestRate = (1 + 0.00417);

        System.out.println("please enter amount saved each mounth");

        double amountSavedMonthly = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("please enter amount of months you will be saving for");
        int amountOfMonthsSaved = input.nextInt();

        int monthCountDown = amountOfMonthsSaved;

        double totalAmount =0;
        double addMonths;
        double intitalAmount = 0;
        while (monthCountDown < 0) {
            addMonths = amountSavedMonthly * monthlyInterestRate + intitalAmount;

            intitalAmount = addMonths;

            totalAmount = intitalAmount;
        }
        double total = totalAmount;
        System.out.println("your total after " + " " + amountOfMonthsSaved + " " + "months is:" + " " + "$" + total);
    }
}
```

Comment: But you might want to to initializing totalamount to some else then zero.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize totalAmount to 0...

Make in while condition greater than 1..