# How can I find the default values of all data types in Java?

Tags: java

I got errors in this program to find the default values of all data types in Java.

```
import java.lang.*;

class Datatypesvalues
{
    public static void main(String var[])
    {
        int i;
        long l;
        float f;
        double d;
        char ch;
        boolean bool;
        System.out.println(+ by);
        System.out.println(+ sh);
        System.out.println(+ i);
        System.out.println(+ l);
        System.out.println(+ f);
        System.out.println(+ d);
        System.out.println(+ ch);
        System.out.println(bool);
    }
}
```

Comment: local variables don't have default values

Comment: Basically, what you're trying to achieve is to see which possible values these variables can have?

Comment: You get errors but don't tell us what they are?

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415687/why-are-local-variables-not-initialized-in-java

Comment: "+ by" ?? What does this mean? Where is "by" defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a variable as an instance variable and print it in the function to get the default value.

A local variable will not be initialized to the default value.

Answer (score 1):

> *How can I find the default values of all data types in Java?*

Read *[The Java® Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html)*, e.g., *[JLS §4.12.5. Initial Values of Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5)*:

> - Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is initialized with a default value when it is created (§15.9, §15.10.2):
>
>   - For type byte, the default value is zero, that is, the value of (byte)**0**.
>   - For type short, the default value is zero, that is, the value of (short)**0**.
>   - For type int, the default value is zero, that is, **0**.
>   - For type long, the default value is zero, that is, **0L**.
>   - For type float, the default value is positive zero, that is, **0.0f**.
>   - For type double, the default value is positive zero, that is, **0.0d**.
>   - For type char, the default value is the null character, that is, **'\u0000'**.
>   - For type boolean, the default value is **false**.
>   - For all reference types (§4.3), the default value is **null**.

It goes on to say:

> - A **local variable** (§14.4, §14.14) **must be explicitly given a value** before it is used, by either initialization (§14.4) or assignment (§15.26), in a way that can be verified using the rules for definite assignment (§16 (Definite Assignment)).

Which is the problem with your code. You didn't *explicitly* assign a value to your *local variables*.

Answer (score 0):

You defined your variables inside the main function which makes them *local* variables and they don't have initial values. You have to initialize them before using. Otherwise you'll get the not initialized error.

You have to use *instance* variables declared outside any method to have initial values. Study the scope of variables. This page is helpful:
*[Java - Variable Types](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_variable_types.htm)*

```
class example
{
    public static int a; 

    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```