# Why adding one else statement is changing whole scenario?

Tags: java, if-statement, compiler-errors

In Java if we provide following statement, it will produce compilation error:

```
class A {

public static void main(String[] args){
    int i = 10;
    int j;
    if(i == 10) {
       j = 20;
    }
    System.out.println(j);
   }
}
```

But in the following statement, no compilation error:

```
class A{ 

public static void main(String[] args){
    int i = 10;
    int j;
    if(i == 10) {
       j = 20;
     }
    else {
       j = 30;
     }
    System.out.println(j);
    }
  }
```

Neither this produces compilation error:

```
class A{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       final int i = 10;
       int j;
       if(i == 10){
          j = 20;
         }
       System.out.println(j);
      }
     }
```

What is the reason?

Comment: In your second code snippet, because of your `if-else` `j` is guaranteed to be initialized eventually in one way or the other.

Comment: The last code doesn't compile since `j` is not declated. Not sure what you expected. But a local variable [must be initialized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415687/why-are-local-variables-not-initialized-in-java) before being used. Which is what the linked question explains, with the same code as you have. Look also at the "Related" questions containing the exact same error.

Comment: @Tunaki  yeah there were some minor mistakes, now you can check it and the link you provided was different from this question

Comment: That is exactly the same code as your first example. Please, refer to the linked question and all of its related questions. A local variable **must be** initialized.

Comment: @Tunaki My last example may be little bit same but I have declared `int i`as `final`. Due to this change, last one gets compiled but not the first one, even though in both `j` isn't initialized.

Comment: Why are you focusing on what the compiler will do? [The Java Language Specification mandates the code **not** to compile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415687/why-are-local-variables-not-initialized-in-java). It would be an error for the compiler to compile that code. It doesn't even matter that the `if` is always true: the spec says that code must not compile, regardless of what the checked conditions actually are.

Answer (score 1):

In the first snippet, the compiler doesn't analyze the value of `i` to determine that `if(i == 10)` would always be true and hence `j` would also be initialized.

Therefore, as far as the compiler is concerned, if the condition is evaluated to false, `j` is never initialized and cannot be accessed.

The second snippet is guaranteed to always initialize `j`, either in the `if` clause or the `else` clause. Therefore it passes compilation.

Comment: it's an initialisation problem my friend.

Comment: This wouldn't be a problem if `j` was a class field.

Comment: @MuratK. That's true.

Comment: @MuratK. But only because class fields are always initialized (with a default if necessary).

Comment: @Eran Then what will you say about this? `final int i =10; int j; if(i ==10) { j = 20;} System.out.println(j);` No compilation error.

Comment: @Pr4njal About what?

Comment: @Tunaki How was it duplicate to the one you marked? Atleast have some decency for the beginners