# Local variable array of ints defaults to zero

Tags: java, arrays, int, local-variables

Why is it that when an array of 'ints' is made as a local variable they default to zero?

```
       public static void main(String [] args) {
           int []arrayInts = new int[5];
           for(int i: arrayInts)
                System.out.println(i);
           //Prints out zeros 
       }
```

While if an 'int' variable is declared as a local variable it does not get initialized.

```
       public static void main(String [] args) {            
           int a;
            System.out.println(a);
           //Compilation error: The local variable a may not have been initialized
       }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415687/why-are-local-variables-not-initialized-in-java

Comment: Because it's in the Java specification that it arrays get initialized with zero. Local variables are not (fields are).

Comment: Right-o.  Basically because "that's how it works."  Slightly more detail: because the Java spec says so.  Local variables are *always* uninitialized, and arrays created with `new` are *always* initialized.  Java is 100% consistent in that regard.

Comment: Think of array values as member variables on the array object, which always have a default value.

Comment: Short answer is that the `new` keyword initialises all objects created with it by default. "Stack" allocated objects are not initialised by default because the compiler can check at compile time if there's a danger of you using a stack variable before it's initialised, the same is not true of variables whose memory is dynamically allocated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two examples aren't comparable.

In the first one, you are ***actively*** initializing your array.  [The default value](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5) for an array of ints is 0.

In the second example, you've ***not*** initialized the variable `a`, either explicitly or implicitly, and you're attempting to make use of it.  Java will complain about this action.

Comment: Right.  The examples might seem comparable to someone new, but they aren't.  `new` is special and does things, like initialize arrays, that a plain local variable doesn't.  It's a big difference even if it's only one little keyword.

Comment: @markspace:  You overlooked something important: the assignment operator.  You can `new` things up in an application all day without ever assigning it to a variable.  You can declare variables without assigning values to them.  But if you try to use a variable that *hasn't* been assigned with some value, you're going to have a compilation error.