# v variable is been initialized

Tags: java, initialization

I did not understand the error: `v variable is been initialized` In the call of the method `less(k, v),` inside the `insert()` method, because the variable v is initialized in line above... But even so the compiler gave me the error. My code is to insert a key in two priority queue, I added a test that i am doing with integers.

```
    public class MedianPQ <Key extends Comparable<Key>>{
      private MaxPq left;
      private MinPq right;

      public MedianPQ(int N, int M) {
        left = new MaxPq(N);
        right = new MinPq(M);
      }

      private boolean less( Key k, Key v) {
        return k.compareTo(v) < 0;
      }

      private boolean great( Key k, Key v) {
        return k.compareTo(v) > 0;
      }

      public void insert(Key k) {
        Key v;
        if( left.isEmpty() && right.isEmpty()) v = k; // initial
        else {
          if( less(k, v) && (left.size() < right.size() + 1)) {   //error
            left.insert(k);
          }
          else if( great(k, v) && (right.size() < left.size() + 1)) {
            right.insert(k);
          }
          else {
            if( left.size() == right.size() + 1) {
              right.insert(v);
              left.insert(k);
              v = (Key)left.max();
            }
            else {
              left.insert(v);
              right.insert(k);
              v = (Key)right.min();
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MedianPQ median = new MedianPQ(100, 100);
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for( int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      median.insert(rnd.nextInt(50));
    }
```

Comment: It's initialized inside an `if` statement. What should the value of `v` be if the `if` expression evaluates to `false`?

Comment: You're only conditionally initializing `v`.

Comment: @4castle I misread the code.  But the initialization explanation is correct, only thing is that I don't know what that default value should be.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Why are you reading from `v` before writing to it?

Comment: Edited my question to be more clear. I don't know how to initialize the variable.

Comment: @MarcelodeSousa Please consider accepting and / or voting my answer if it has been useful

Comment: Please, upvote my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

v is declared as a local variable, but you never assign an initial value before reassigning another value

```
public void insert(Key k) {
```

> `Key v = null;`
>
> Or
>
> `Key v = new Key();`

```
if( left.isEmpty() && right.isEmpty()) v = k; // initial

else 
{
    if( less(k, v) && (left.size() < right.size() + 1))
    {
        left.insert(k);
    }
    else if( great(k, v) && (right.size() < left.size() + 1)) 
    {
        right.insert(k);
    }
    else 
    {
       if( left.size() == right.size() + 1) 
       {
           right.insert(v);
           left.insert(k);
           v = (Key)left.max();
        }
        else 
        {
           left.insert(v);
           right.insert(k);
           v = (Key)right.min();
        }       
  }
```

Comment: `Key v = null` is not an initialization statement, because it will already default to being `null`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Local variables [don't have default values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/415687/5743988).

Comment: @4castle But are you saying that, if checked, it would have a value other than `null`?  Then what would that value be?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen In any situation where the compiler notices it might have to use a default value, the compiler just throws an error, so there's no way to test it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have always initialized the classes and strings with null, since the values ​​that accept null, must be initialized in this way.

Test it yourself and you will see that null is valid as initialization

Comment: @4castle I have always initialized the classes and strings with null, since the values ​​that accept null, must be initialized in this way. Test it yourself and you will see that null is valid as initialization