# How to return an int value stuck in a for loop

Tags: java, int

Lets assume Num is simply 3.

```
 public static int income(Scanner console, int number)
{
int incomeNum = console.nextInt();
int amount;
for(int i = 0; i <= number; i++)
{
    System.out.println("Next income amount?");
    incomeNum = console.nextInt();
    amount += incomeNum;
}
return amount;
}
```

I need the incomeNum to add itself up when the user puts in a number and store it into amount and have that amount be returned to the main. I'm stuck because it says the amount is not initialized...

Comment: Change `int amount;` to `int amount = 0;`. You can't add `incomeNum` to `amount` when `amount` has no value.

Comment: @Gendarme thanks a lot!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are local variables not initialized in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415687/why-are-local-variables-not-initialized-in-java)

Comment: @Gendarme nope. no duplicates

Comment: On line 9, did you mean to use "=+"? or should it be "+="?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable might not have been initialized error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448843/variable-might-not-have-been-initialized-error)

Comment: @MoreFoam Yes, I saw that error when working on my code and fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the right idea, but your problem is that you actually dont give `int amount` a value.

Try `int amount = 0;`

Answer (score 3):

You just need to give (amount) a value from the beginning.

```
int amount = 0;
```

everything else remains the same. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You have to initialize the `int amount = 0;` in order.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

"A local variable in Java is a variable that's declared within the body of a method. And in Java local variables don't have a default value (i.e. not even zero or null)."
So if you use a local variable without first initializing it, the compiler will throw an error when trying to run the program.

The same happened with your local variable "`amount`" and once you initialized it with `amount = 0;` , now it works. Hope this clarifies the concept!