# Not sure about default initialization of variables in Java

Tags: java, variables, initialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Uninitialized variables and members in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268814/uninitialized-variables-and-members-in-java)
>   [Why are local variables not initialized in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415687/why-are-local-variables-not-initialized-in-java)

In `Java` variables have default value, right? Even arrays are initialized by compiler.
So I can't understand the following:

```
int c;  
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){  
   c = i + 5;  
}  
System.out.println("Result = "+c);
```

Why do I get a compiler error:

> The local variable c may not have been initialized

Isn't `c` initialized to `0` by default by compiler?
So why do I get this error and why does the error go away if I explicitely do `int c = 0`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No** local variables must have to be initialized, class field variables has the default value

> Local variables are slightly different; the compiler never assigns a default value to an uninitialized local variable. If you cannot initialize your local variable where it is declared, make sure to assign it a value before you attempt to use it. Accessing an uninitialized local variable will result in a compile-time error [[...]](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Comment: 1)Where is this quote from? 2)Does this apply also to arrays?

Comment: Yes it applies to Object aswell, the link is provided at the end of quote

Answer (score 1):

Beucase `forloop` is conditional loop. And as per compiler `c`  might not have initialized if did not went into that conditional loop

Comment: Ah!Ok. So the compiler here is not smart enough to understand that it will go in the loop?