# i and j not being initialized. But I already wrote int i and int j. What is wrong

Tags: java, initialization, geometry, local-variables

When I try to compile it, Eclipse says that i and j has not been initialized. What am I doing wrong? The question is about creating a circle.

```
public class Question2 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int x = 14;
        int y = 8;
        int radius = 5;


        DrawMeACircle(x,y,radius);

    }

    public static void DrawMeACircle(int x, int y, int radius)
    {

        int i, j;
        int gridsize = 99;
        int loop1;
        loop1 = ((x-i)*(x-i))+((y-j)*(y-j));
                // The problem is here (in the line above), it say i and j has not been initialized.

                int loop2 = loop1-radius*radius; 
                int c = radius-1; 

        for (i=0; i<gridsize; i++)
        {
            //System.out.print("#");
            for (j=0; j<gridsize; j++)
            {
                if(loop2 >=0 && loop2<= c )
                    {System.out.print("#");}
                else
                    {System.out.print(" ");}

            }
            System.out.print("\n"); 

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Local variables must be initialized with a value:

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
```

Only class int variables will be set to 0 if not explicitly initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize your `i and j`

```
int i =0, j=0;
```

as local variables must be initialized.

As jcoder answered in this related question:- [Uninitialized variables and members in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268814/uninitialized-variables-and-members-in-java)

> Instance variables of object type default to being initialized to
>   null. **Local variables of object type are not initialized by default
>   and it's a compile time error to access an undefined variable**.

Also the **[javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5)** says:-

> A local variable (§14.4, §14.14) must be explicitly given a value
>   before it is used, by either initialization (§14.4) or assignment
>   (§15.26), in a way that can be verified using the rules for definite
>   assignment

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize `i` and `j` with a value, before you can do this `loop1 = ((x-i)*(x-i))+((y-j)*(y-j));`  For example `int i = 0; int j = 0;` Or whatever value to need it to be for your equation

Answer (score 0):

The scope of i and j is limited to the `public static void main(String[] args)` method. 
declaring it in the class body. 
ie. 
     `public class Question2` 
     `{`
          `static int i, j;`
`public static void main(String[] args)`
          `{`
             `i = j = 0;`
`}`
`......... your rest of the code`
`}`

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a variable means reserving memory space to store a value, that you already did, but, when you are going to use a variable and your IDE (in this particular case eclipse) can't find a line where you asigned the variable an initial value (or where you **initialized** said variable) so, you should set that first value before using the variable in any kind of operations.

```
int x;

system.out.println(x+1); // this line would cause the exception you got because x has not              
                         // an initial value

x=0;
system.out.println(x+1); // now x has an "initial" value and there should be no exception
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `int` variables `i` and `j` when you haven't yet initialized them. At some point in your code, you're going to have to initialize them before you use them.

```
int i, j;
String s = "Hello"
if (s.equals("Hello")){
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    // Horray! We can now use i and j!
}
```