# Why local variable MUST be initialized and why instance variables MUST NOT be initialized before using?

Tags: java, initialization

I've noticed that the JAVA allows to use uninitialized instance variable but it blocks to use uninitialized local variables. I want to know **why the language is saying so**?

Note : This is not the first post of this kind. I've visited below questions too. But couldn't  find the exact reason for WHY?
This question may be a duplicate one of the following:

- [Uninitialized variables and members in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268814/uninitialized-variables-and-members-in-java)
- [Why are local variables not initialized in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415687/why-are-local-variables-not-initialized-in-java)

Comment: It's in the accepted answer on the first question: "It's not practical to enforce definite assignment on fields." That explains why there's a difference. It's not clear whether you're asking why local variables *must* be initialized, or why fields *don't* have to be initialized.

Comment: The best answer to your question would be found in the second thread you linked in your question in my opinion. I don't see the point in asking again, try to read that more carefully. Edit: also, like Jon Skeet says just as well.

Comment: @Jon Skeet : Yes Jon! I'm unclear why local variable must be initialized and why instance variables must not be initialized!

Comment: @Namalak: No, my question was *which* of those you weren't sure on. Basically the existing questions provide answers to both - it would just change which I'd cast a close vote on...

Comment: Sorry Jon! I didn't get it once!. Comparatively it is much unclear that why local variable must be initialized by force.

Comment: I am not sure of your premise - local (method/code block) variables "must be initialised"? How about perfectly valid code `int localVar; some code; some code; localVar = initvalue;`? Or are you asking why Jva does not allow you to **use** local variable **before** they are initialised? This is due to the fact that local variables are allocated in the stack and are **dirty** memory, it is inefficient to ask the system to clear this memory every time.

Comment: @Germann : Yes I'm asking about why Java does not allow you to use local variable before they are initialised?

Comment: In this case the answer is in the last sentence of my previous comment. To clarify: instance variables only need to be initialised once per object life cycle, **new** local variables are allocated on **every** invocation of the method/code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know,

- **Instance variable**: will be initial at the run time when class initial and default of instance variable is null => instance variable will error at run time.
- **Local variable**: Unlike class and instance variables, a local variable is fussy about where you position the declaration for it: You must place the declaration before the first statement that actually uses the variable. => local variable error with syntax error.

  ref: [Local variable in java](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/local-variables-in-java.html)

Answer (score 1):

> I've noticed that the JAVA allows to use uninitialized instance
>   variable.

No, the compiler initialize instance variables, if you don't initialize.

Comment: True, but not an answer.