# Why it is not possible to call a static function defined within a class through reference variable of the class?

Tags: java, reference, static

I have a question that why this code is giving me an error while i am trying to call a static function defined within a class through a class reference and it makes possible to call a static function when i am creating an object of a reference.

```
public class Example
{
public static void main(String args[])  
{
Example t;
t.method();//getting error
Example t1=new Example t1();
t1.method();//it runs successfully
}
public static void method()
{
System.out.println("NullPointerException");
}
}
```

Comment: t not inistialized, it's null.

Comment: Be more specific than "giving an error". Specify compile time or runtime and the error message.

Comment: @J.Rush `t` is not null, it has not been initialised. Local variables, unlike instance variable, *must* be explicitly initialised.

Comment: @ABFORCE Have you actually tried? This code gives a compiler error, so doesn't run. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268814/uninitialized-variables-and-members-in-java) about uninitialised locals.

Answer (score 3):

You should not call a static method on an instance of the class. You should use name of the class itself:

```
Example.method()
```

Also when you declare a variable and left it without initialization, It will not be initialized (Local variables) and when you try to call a method on it, you will get error

Comment: _You can not call a static method on an instance of the class._ You can, but you shouldn't.

Comment: @ggovan Yes you are right, I will edit it

Comment: _Also when you declare a variable and left it without initialization, It will be initialized with null_. Only on instance variables, not locals. Hence the compiler complaint that the questioner is getting.

Comment: @ggovan My mean is on non-primitive types that inherited from `Object`

Comment: @ggovan I've googled and read some articles, yes you are right it is not null

Answer (score 1):

t is not initialised when you call `t.method();`. You therefore get a **NullPointer** on the non-instanciated **t** object.

Comment: `t` isn't actually used as it is a static method call. You won't get a NPE here.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Example
{
public static void main(String args[])  
{
Example t;       // t points to nothing (not even null, actually, its as if it doesn't exist at all)
 t.method();//getting error  // how can you call a method of example with a reference to nothing.
Example t1=new Example t1(); // t1 points to an Example object.
t1.method();//it runs successfully // works fine , but is not suggested as the method is at class level, not at instance level. use Example.method() 
}
public static void method()
{
System.out.println("NullPointerException");
}
}
```

Comment: When `t.method()` is first called `t` is not null! It has not been initialised. If `t` were null then the code would compile and the method would be called correctly as it is a static method call.

Comment: @ggovan -Thanks.. Ya.. Pretty dumb of me to use "null"... :)

Answer (score 0):

that is possible, but if you want to call anything through a reference, you need to instantiate it first.

do remember also: Java has methods, not functions. So, change:

```
Example t;
```

in

```
Example t = new Example();
```

and try again

Comment: can't he just do Example.method() ?

Comment: since it is static, yes he can, and yes, he should.
but the question was: why can't I do it through an instance.

Comment: And you should be answering it with - "Its not good to use an instance to access a static method" :)